# Can I change IP address to domain name inside server system?

Tags: domains, dns, iis, windows

I can access my server only by ip:port, because I have some unusual ports open. I can make URL redirect inside the domain service, but on client's browser it will display just ip and port and therefore will not be secure. Is there any way to in IIS 10 to redirect connection from ip to domain name internaly, not using external dns?